# Why slider do not display intermediate results sent by signal from Connections?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml

Why slider and label do not display intermediate results sent by signal from Connections? Slider and label only display the final result. How to make it appear consistently?

test.py

```
    class Test(QObject):
        percent = pyqtSignal(int, arguments=['percent'])
    
        @pyqtSlot()
        def start(self):
            for i in range(101):
                self.percent.emit(i)
                print(i)
                time.sleep(0.1)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        test = Test()
        app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
        engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
        engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("Test", test)
        engine.load('test.qml')
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is test.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 100
    RowLayout {
        Slider {
            id: slider
            implicitWidth: 300
            from: 1
            value: 1
            to: 100

        }
        Label {
            id: label
            width: 100
            text: "0"
        }
        Button {
            highlighted: true
            text: "Go"
            onClicked: {
                Test.start()
            }
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: Test
        function onPercent(percent) {
            slider.value = percent
            label.text = percent
        }
    }
}
```

Slider and label only display the final result.
How to make it appear consistently?

Comment: I think you should do this asynchronously, I mean the test should be run in a different thread so UI thread will be able to update the slider.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test(QObject):
    percent = pyqtSignal(int, arguments=['percent'])

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.threadTest)
        t1.start()

    def threadTest(self):
        for i in range(101):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.percent.emit(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("Test", test)
    engine.load('test.qml')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

it works.